# Error on lambda operators in android

Tags: android

i want to write a code using Runnable method using lambda operators but i got an error of 
Error:(40, 33) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
Here is my code:`

```
public void countDownStart(){
    handler= new Handler();
    runnable= (Runnable) () -> {
       handler.postDelayed((Runnable) this, 1000);
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            Date futureDate= dateFormat.parse("2017-03-31");
            Date currentDate= new Date();
            if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)){
                long diff = futureDate.getTime()- currentDate.getTime();
                long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                diff -= minutes * (60* 1000);
                long seconds = diff / 1000;
             txtTimerDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
             txtTimerHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
             txtTimerMinute.setText("" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
             txtTimerSecond.setText("" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
            }else{
                tvEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvEvent.setText("The Event Started");
                textViewGone();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: What is your JAVA verson?

Comment: have you searched the error message on google?

Answer (score 1):

you are using java 7. lambda expressions are supported since java 8. problem in android is, only android n (7.0) or higher supports java 8. if you still want to use lambdas in lower android versions, you can use libraries like [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), but these libraries often don't support all functionalities of java lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added following instructions in your build.gradle file?

```
defaultConfig {

    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```